# SFML 2.0 Targeting a player by a single turret

Tags: c++, sfml

At the beginning - sorry for my english (i'm still learning).
I've created a turret which targets player. It works fine but when i'm moving around within the range of tower, turret no longer targets me. Just take a look at this code and run this in your compilator.

```
 int detection (sf::Sprite statek,sf::RectangleShape linia,sf::Texture textstatku)
{
    sf::FloatRect rect, rect2;
    rect = linia.getGlobalBounds();
    rect2 = statek.getGlobalBounds();

    if(rect2.intersects(rect))
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

sf::Event evente;
sf::RenderWindow okno ( sf::VideoMode(500,500,32)," TURRET TEST ");
sf::Texture textturreta;
textturreta.loadFromFile ("C:\\Users\\Darono\\C++\\Projekty\\IN PROGGRES\\Single turret\\Debug\\turret.png");
sf::CircleShape turret (20.0,100);
turret.setTexture((sf::Texture *)&textturreta);
turret.setPosition (240,240);


sf::Texture Lufatext;
Lufatext.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Darono\\C++\\Projekty\\IN PROGGRES\\Single turret\\Debug\\Lufa.png");

sf::Sprite lufa;
lufa.setTexture(Lufatext);

sf::Texture gracztext;
gracztext.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Darono\\C++\\Projekty\\IN PROGGRES\\Single turret\\Debug\\gracz.png");
sf::Sprite gracz(gracztext);


int orginY=turret.getPosition().y+20;
int orginX=turret.getPosition().x+20;

lufa.setPosition(turret.getPosition().x+20,turret.getPosition().y+20);
lufa.setOrigin (2,-20);

sf::RectangleShape liniastrzalu(sf::Vector2f(1,200));
liniastrzalu.setOrigin(0,-20);
liniastrzalu.setPosition(turret.getPosition().x+20,turret.getPosition().y+20);


int a =0;
while (okno.isOpen())
{
    if (gracz.getPosition().y >= turret.getPosition().y-240||gracz.getPosition().y <= turret.getPosition().y+280)
    {

        if (detection(gracz,liniastrzalu,textturreta)== 1)
        {
            std::cout <<"lol";
        }
        if (detection(gracz,liniastrzalu,textturreta)==2)
        {
            lufa.rotate(1);
            liniastrzalu.rotate(1);
        }


    }
    while (okno.pollEvent(evente))
    {
        //lufa obraca się razem z kołem
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
            gracz.move(-2,0);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
            gracz.move(2,0);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        {
            gracz.move(0,2);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
            gracz.move(0,-2);
        }

    }



    okno.display();
    okno.clear();
    okno.draw(turret);
    okno.draw(lufa);
    okno.draw(gracz);
    //okno.draw(liniastrzalu);


}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow a few best practices:

Your game loop consists of 3 main parts: handling user input, updating your game world and drawing your game world. Although you do this, you have the order mixed up. You seem to update your game world before handling user input.

Drawing in SFML consists of cleaning the surface, drawing and presenting *in that order*.

```
okno.clear();
okno.draw(turret);
okno.draw(lufa);
okno.draw(gracz);
okno.display();
```

Notice how I put the display call to the end.

You don't need to call your detection method twice. Call it once and store the result in a variable, then use that variable.

Fix those things first, because they will cause a lot of problems that may hide your real problem or cause problems when your code is fine.

Comment: i've updated my code, but still i don't know what to do next.

Comment: @Darono You could post your updated code. In addition, maybe you can build a small example that works (or rather has the same problems) without textures, because we don't have those textures and therefore cannot test your code. You may want to use english variable and function names, so the community can follow you easier.

Comment: Job's done. Thanks for help and some tips, but i've already found a tutorial made by autor of sfml.